# HTML Purifier - iframe and scripts

Tags: php, html, xss, htmlpurifier

I'm using [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) in my project.

My html is something like this. (containing simple html element + script + iframe)

```
<p>content...<p>
<iframe></iframe>
<script>alert('abc');</script>
<p>content2</p>
```

With default config, it turned into this

```
<p>content...</p>
<p></p>
<p>Content2</p>
```

But if I set the config like this...

```
$config->set('HTML.Trusted', true);
$config->set('HTML.SafeIframe', true);
```

I got this

```
<p>content...</p>
<p>
    <iframe></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
    alert('abc');
    //--><!]]></script>
</p>
<p>content2</p>
```

Is there anyway to use HTML Purifier to completely remove 'script' tag but preserve 'iframe' tag? Or other alternative to HTML Purifier?

I've tried

```
$config->set('Filter.YouTube', true);
$config->set('URI.SafeIframeRegexp', '%^https://(www.youtube.com/embed/|player.vimeo.com/video/)%');
```

But it turned out that the 'script' tag still there.

***[edited]***

full example.

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();

$html = "<p>content...<p><iframe ...></iframe><script>alert('abc');</script><p>content2</p>";

$config->set(
        'HTML.ForbiddenElements',
        'script'
    );

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

$clean_html = $purifier->purify($html);
```

Result

```
<p>content...</p><p></p><p>content2</p>
```

Comment: Have you considered reversing your check to specify the ["forbidden elements"](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.ForbiddenElements)?

Comment: @Script47 It removed both script and iframe tag. T^T

Comment: Did you specify just the `script` tag? Edit your post to show your updated code.

Comment: @Script47 I've edited my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were half on the right track. If you set [`HTML.SafeIframe`](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.SafeIframe) to `true` and [`URI.SafeIframeRegexp`](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#URI.SafeIframeRegexp) to the URLs you want to accept (`%^https://(www.youtube.com/embed/|player.vimeo.com/video/)%` works fine), an input example of:

```
<p>content...<p>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/blep"></iframe>
<script>alert('abc');</script>
<p>content2</p>
```

...turns into...

```
<p>content...</p><p>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/blep"></iframe>

</p><p>content2</p>
```

**Explanation**: `HTML.SafeIframe` allows the `<iframe>` tag, but HTML Purifier still expects a whitelist for the URLs that the iframe can contain, since otherwise an `<iframe>` opens too much malicious potential. `URI.SafeIframeRegexp` supplies the whitelist (in the form of a regex that needs to be matched).

See if that works for you!

#### Code

This is the code that made the transformation I just mentioned:

```
$dirty = '<p>content...<p>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/blep"></iframe>
<script>alert(\'abc\');</script>
<p>content2</p>';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.SafeIframe', true);
$config->set('URI.SafeIframeRegexp', '%^https://(www.youtube.com/embed/|player.vimeo.com/video/)%');

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

$clean = $purifier->purify($dirty);
```

#### Regarding HTML.Trusted

I implore you to never set `HTML.Trusted` to `true` if you don't fully trust each and every one of the people submitting the HTML.

Amongst other things, it allows forms in your input HTML to survive the purification unmolested, which (if you're purifying for a website, which I assume you are) makes phishing attacks trivial. It allows your input to use style tags which survive unscathed. There are some things it will still strip (any HTML tag that HTML Purifier doesn't actually know anything about, i.e. most HTML5 tags being some of them, various JavaScript attribute handlers as well), but there are enough attack vectors that you might as well not be purifying if you use this directive. As [Ambush Commander once put it](http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?2,4715,4716#msg-4716):

> You shouldn't be using %HTML.Trusted anyway; it really ought to be named %HTML.Unsafe or something.

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks! > <
(Also thanks for the explanation.)

Answer (score -2):

Consider using a full-fledged HTML parser like Masterminds [html5-php](https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php). HTML code would then be parsed without undesired alterations like wrapping `IFRAME` in `P`, and you would be able to manipulate the resulting DOM tree the way you want, including removing some elements while keeping other ones.

For example, the following code could be used for removing `SCRIPT` elements from the document:

```php
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('script') as $script) {
    $script->parentNode->removeChild($script);
}
```

And note that code like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
    alert('abc');
//--><!]]></script>`
```

is obsolete. The modern HTML5 equivalent code is :

```html
<script>alert('abc');</script>
```

exactly as in your source code before being processed by HTML Purifier.

Comment: HTML Purifier is a full-fledged HTML parser. The `<p>` tags are likely coming from [the `AutoFormat.AutoParagraph` setting](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#AutoFormat.AutoParagraph). It's also a lot more fully featured than a mere parser.

Comment: @ceejayoz Does HTML Purifier allow to process the DOM document further with no need for reparsing with another HTML parser?

Comment: That's kinda besides the point, isn't it? The point of HTML Purifier isn't "I need to parse an HTML document". It's "I want to apply a variety of potentially complex rules to sanitize this HTML".

Comment: @ceejayoz Sanitizing HTML code is often just a single stage in a multi-stage processing. With DOM, we can do anything, while with HTML Purifier we can only sanitize, and apparently with undesired/unexpected DOM-tree alterations enabled by default, and with generating obsolete code by default.

Comment: You're proposing replacing that with "write all these complex rules yourself", though, which adds all sorts of its own problems. HTML Purifier does a whole bunch of useful, well-tested stuff out-of-the-box. If OP has *additional* parser needs, they may want to consider a more generalist parser (or accept the overhead of a second parse), but there's little evidence of that in their question.

Comment: @ceejayoz I explained why I recommend _considering_ using a full-fledged parser. DOM is quite simple to use to me and provides more control and flexibility. Different answers, different options. It’s up to the OP to decide what to choose.

Comment: _"For example, the following code could be used for removing SCRIPT elements from the document"_ - this wouldn't make the code significantly safer, e.g. a suitable `onmouseover` attribute on an `<img>` tag would still let the attacker execute any javascript they like. Blacklist approaches are generally problematic. HTML Purifier is an HTML parser combined with a default safe whitelist and _understanding_ of HTML. It understands what elements are safe (and how they relate to each other, and how that might cause additional problems), so you don't have to research it all yourself. :)

Comment: @pinkgothic Yes, I usually use whitelist of elements and attributes, but the OP asked specifically about removing scripts.

Comment: @MaratTanalin Not to belabor the point, but this is precisely why I criticized your answer. OP presumably wants to prevent users from *injecting scripts of any kind*, not just stop them from using the `<script>` tag.

Comment: @ceejayoz DOM allows to remove attributes.

Comment: Yes, but you have to a) know to do that and b) implement it and c) implement it all *properly* on your own. Or... you can use a well-tested, community-supported existing solution. Same reason frameworks exist, are popular, and usually recommended as a starting point.

Comment: @ceejayoz Everyone (and not just the OP) is free to use what they want. HTML Purifier is not the only option. Just like DOM is not too. Both are possible options. Let’s stop this unhelpful conversation.